# Generate HTTPS link in Web API using Url.Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to generate an absolute url to an ASP.NET Web API for a later callback/redirection.

The link can be generated using

```
Url.Link("RouteName", new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" });
```

This returns the correct Url, however, I need it to always be https.  Url.Link appears to generate a url using the scheme of the current request.  For example, if the request generating the url is something like http://www.myhost.com/controller/generateUrl then Url.Link generates an http url.  If the request generating the url is https://www.myhost.com/controller/generateUrl then Url.Link generates an https url.

The url needs to always be generated using https.  Is there a parameter or route value that can be passed to Url.Link to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible with `Url.Link()`

I would check the HttpRequest and change it to https to get all `Url.Link()` to return an https link.

Something like:

```
        if (Url.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            var secureUrlBuilder = new UriBuilder(Url.Request.RequestUri);
            secureUrlBuilder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
            Url.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(secureUrlBuilder.ToString());
        }

        // should now return https
        Url.Link("RouteName", new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" });
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was something simpler built in but doesn't look like it exists.  One thing that also had to happen was that the Port on UriBuilder needed to be explicitly set, otherwise it kept port 80 and caused an error.

Comment: i.e. `secureUrlBuilder.Port = 443;`