# Password reset link using identity and web api

Tags: email, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, identity

I'm trying to create in my WebApi controller an action to send an email with a passwors reset link. But when the email arrives, the link url is "http://Account/ResetPassword/........"

Please, note the site url is missing from de link. I need something like "http://www.domain.com/account/resetpassword/........."

This is my code. Thanks!

```
    [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("ForgotPassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForgotPassword(string email)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email is required");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = await AppUserManager.FindByNameAsync(email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            string code = await AppUserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

            urlHelper.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new RouteValueDictionary(new { userId = user.Id, code }), protocol: Request.RequestUri.Scheme);

            await AppUserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Redefinir Senha", "Redefina sua senha clicando <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aqui</a>");

            return Ok();
        }

        return NotFound();

    }
```

Comment: [`UrlHelper` is not available nor compatible with Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245065/asp-net-web-api-generate-url-using-url-action). You have to construct the URI manually.